# Cursor not closed after filtering

Tags: android, filter, android-cursoradapter

I'm trying to implement a filter function for a list of database entries using a custom CursorAdapter and ContentProvider. The code actually does work as expected, but causes warnings and in some cases even errors. In CursorAdapter I overrode **runQueryOnBackgroundThread** that performs the filtering and returns a cursor:

```
@Override
public Cursor runQueryOnBackgroundThread(CharSequence constraint) {

  if (getFilterQueryProvider() != null) {
    return getFilterQueryProvider().runQuery(constraint);
  }

  if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
    return context.getContentResolver().query(DBContentProvider.URI_LOGS, null,
        LRMDatabase.LogTable.TYPE + " >= " + this.filterType, null, sqlOrder);
  } else {
    return context.getContentResolver().query(
        DBContentProvider.URI_LOGS, null,
        LRMDatabase.LogTable.TYPE + " >= " + this.filterType  + " AND " +
        LRMDatabase.LogTable.MSG + " LIKE '%" + constraint.toString() + "%'", null,
        this.sqlOrder);
  }
}
```

and in my corresponding activity I used a **TextWatcher** in oder to filter the data set:

```
private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {    
  }

  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
  }

  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
  }
};
```

My problem now is, that every time when I previously called **onTextChanged** (otherwise everything works fine) and then returned from my activity where I display the filtered data set, I get a warning like "*Unclosed Cursor detected*" or even an error like "*Finalizing a Cursor that has not been deactivated or closed*". Any ideas why this happens?

I am aware that I request an initial cursor to display the unfiltered list and that this cursor should be closed after returning from my activity (This seems to work). I am also aware that along with my filtering request I create a new cursor that - according to [ANDROID developers reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#runQueryOnBackgroundThread%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) - should be swaped with the old cursor after returning from **runQueryOnBackgroundThread** and thereby the old cursor should be closed. For some reason this seems to go wrong!